# How webpage security works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, web

This question is in my mind for long time, As a web developer, i tried to find answer over the years but failed miserably. Hence, planned to approach the experts here. There are lots of heavy security available in regular java/J2EE apps for session hijacking, so lets discuss the simple javascript app.

For eg: A normal Javascript Application launches (AngularJS), **www.example.com/#** welcome, after successful login, and user can navigate to the next page, like '**www.example.com/#page1/**', the navigation continues.

Suppose, now user2 without logging in, get to know the url path '**www.example.com/#page1/**', and tries to launch it, the access denies. But how this is happening under the hood. How the javascript handles the session/client id, and tracing.

Any sample coding project that i can refer for this ?

Apologize if the question sounds too dumb.

Thanks,
David

Comment: See docs for back-end software that does this, e.g. [Express](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

Comment: Login happens at the back-end right?  Only the info about the logged in user will be stored in session.

Comment: Security will mainly be done on the server, the only _security_ in a JavaScript application will be to redirect the user if the server say's they're not logged in (Normally a 401 response). So when User2 navigates to **/#page1/** the server will return a 401

Answer (score 3):

Security is only done on server-side. Your application, including the html, styles and javascript is available for everyone in the browser. You will get all the sensitive data via ajax calls from the server. During this API call you can check credentials or verify an authentication token from the header. Normally you would do something of the following:

### Sessions

Check username/password and create a session with the id of the user, which will be checked on every api call. This is not stateless and you have to avoid it, if you want to create a RESTful api.

### Tokens

Check username/password and save a randomly created token in your database, which you send back to the client. The client will send this token with every request and you will check your database to see if this request is authorized. This is stateless, but requires a query on every request just for authentication.

### JWT

Check username/password and send an encrypted JSON object to the client, which only you can decrypt with your server side secret. The client will send this token with every request and you can authenticate the request just by decrypting the token. This is stateless and does not require you to save the tokens.

Comment: The only caveat I would add to this is that best practice involves configuring a secure data pipeline, e.g. requiring HTTPS (HTTP over TLS/SSL) instead of simple HTTP.

Comment: Hi Jahns, this is a nice explanation, most of the code in our application, just handling the incoming request without any session validation, But still working without any session hijack, is this in-turn handled by the apps server or the framework is taking care of this under the hood. 

BTW, thanks much for your time.